# Push Notifications in python

Tags: python, django, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications

I am attempting to send basic push notifications to GCM and APNS in python. I am experienced in python, but mostly for data analysis/modeling. I have tried [pushjack](https://github.com/dgilland/pushjack) and have successfully sent a push. But there is little documentation on it.

```
from pushjack import GCMClient

client = GCMClient(api_key='API-KEY')

registration_id = 'REG-ID'

notify = {'title': 'Push_test', 'body': 'This is a python test!!', 'icon': ''}

res = client.send([registration_id],
              '',
              notification=notify)
```

But the icon on the actual push does not look right and I cannot send without the icon key in the notify dict. I am not sold on using this module, and am open to using to [django](https://github.com/jleclanche/django-push-notifications), but I have no experience with this and (correct me if I am wrong) seems much too advanced for sending a basic push.

Any help/suggestions would be very much appreciated.

Comment: This package may be a good option for you: https://github.com/jleclanche/django-push-notifications

Comment: Try Firebase SDK instead for your [push notification](https://firebase.google.com/docs/notifications/) needs as it's built for stability and ease of use. However, since you're using Python, you'll be using the helper libraries created by the community: [Pyrebase](https://github.com/thisbejim/Pyrebase), [Python-firebase](http://ozgur.github.io/python-firebase/), [python-firebase](https://github.com/mikexstudios/python-firebase). These options alone should prove that Firebase is a viable pick for your task.